# How can i execute an shell script in my own jenkins pipeline plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

my problem is that i want to execute an script inside my jenkins pipeline plugin, and the 'perf script' command do not work.
My script is:

```
#! /bin/bash
if test $# -lt 2
then
    sudo perf record -F 99 -a -g -- sleep 20
    sudo perf script > info.perf
    echo "voila"
fi  
exit 0
```

My Jenkins can execute sudo so this is not the problem, and in my own Linux Shell this script works perfectly..
How can i solve this?

Comment: Could it be that the redirect in that perf script command does not have write access to info.perf? Remember that the redirect writes as the user your script runs as, not root.

Comment: @StephenKing this could be the problem, cause the info.perf is always empty. How could i give write access to the perf script command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this adding the -i option to perf script command:

```
sudo perf record -F 99 -a -g -- sleep 20
sudo perf script -i perf.data > info.perf
echo "voila"
```

Seems like Jenkins is not able to read perf.data without -i option

Comment: Nice find, more accurate than my answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

If the redirection does not work within the script, try and see if it is working within the DSL Jenkinsfile.

If you call that script with the [`sh` step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#code-sh-code-shell-script) supports `returnStdout` ([JENKINS-26133](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26133)):

```
res = sh(returnStdout: true, script: '/path/to/your/bash/script').trim()
```

You could process the result directly in `res`, bypassing the need for a file.

Comment: Testing your solution, i get this error in Jenkins: "incompatible file format (rerun with -v to learn more)", its like perf script dont recognize the "perf.data"...

Comment: @JuanCarlosFR First, would it work for any other command generating some multi-line output? Just for testing?

Comment: yes, i have been testing with 2 more scripts and it works... the problem is only the perf script command

Comment: @JuanCarlosFR OK, because I know nothing about that script. Maybe some kind of dependency is missing when run in a Jenkins job context?

Comment: i think dependencies should not be a problem, because perf record works perfectly, and perfs commands should use the same dependencies true?

Comment: Looking at http://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html, yes, I suppose so. Is a perf.data generated and accessible by the first `perf record` command?

Comment: yes, precisely im using this perfs commands for generate FlameGraphs, and i have been trying with 'perf record .... | perf script ...' and the same error